# C# - text change event in a text form: is there a better way?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My goal is to change tab's title to the one in the text field, when user enters it. Well, problem is, text form is dynamically created within a procedure, and thus inaccessible from other procedures. I made an event handler, but to my surprise, EventArgs held none of the text field's properties. Code's the following:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewChar();
}
private void NewChar()
{
    TabPage ntab = new TabPage("New char");
    TextBox cname = new TextBox();
    tabControl1.Controls.Add(ntab);
    ntab.Controls.Add(cname);
    cname.Location = new Point(10, 10);
    cname.TextChanged += new EventHandler(cname_TextChanged);
}
```

Finally, I managed to notice, that event's sender value holds text field's current text, so I simply cut this value from sender's string reperesentation:

```
void cname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tmp = sender.ToString();
    int pos = tmp.IndexOf(":");
    string txt = tmp.Substring(pos+1);
    tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = txt;
}
```

Although this works fine, I feel that there's got to be a more gentle way to do this. If you happen to know one, could you please enlighten me?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: AFAIK sender object should be the TextBox object, so you can cast it and get the value: TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender; txt = tb.Text;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than parse out the results of the ToString() you can just cast it to a textbox and then access the Text Directly

```
void cname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt= sender as TextBox;
    if (txt !=null)
          tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = txt.Text;
}
```